# Gaufrette upload image and store in AmazonS3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm using the bundle https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette and this is my configuration:

```
knp_gaufrette: 
    adapters:
        someadapter:
            amazon_s3:
                amazon_s3_id: service.amazon.s3
                bucket_name: %amazon.s3.bucket_name%
                create: true
    filesystems:
        somefilesystem:
            adapter: someadapter
```

I have a form in which I upload a file. My problem is that the file is upload in the /tmp/file directory and then I tried to move this file to amazon:

`$filesystem->get('somefilesystem')->rename($tmpPath , $destinyPath);`

an exception is throw:

`The file "/tmp/phpR4YbZN" was not found.`

It makes sense because the file is not already in amazon and I'm working on that filesystem. But I would like to know how I could to upload a file to AmazonS3 from my local filesystem.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you want to upload images yourself?  Or are you trying to allow others to upload?

Comment: I create a form to upload images for users, the form is working properly and I can see the image in /tmp/file in my server. That I want to do is to take this image from /tmp and upload to amazons3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to do such thing ? :

```
$filesystemMap
   ->get('somefilesystem')
   ->write($destinyPath, file_get_contents($tmpPath))
;`
```

just notice that write method have third "**overwrite**" argument (by default **false**).

You can register stream wrapper and work like with normal php file API/functions. Please see https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle#stream-wrapper for more info.

Comment: @peter, How could you do this with stream wrapper? I read the documentation but I don't understand well the benefits. Thanks