# How to use Gaufrette to upload and store an image into S3 without using the bundle?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I found this http://knplabs.com/blog/give-your-projects-a-gaufrette

and the code sample it provides is

```
<?php

$amazon = new AmazonS3('myKey', 'mySecretKey', 'myToken');
$adapter = new Gaufrette\Adapter\AmazonS3($amazon, 'my_bucket');
$filesystem = new Gaufrette\Filesystem($adapter);

if ( ! $filesystem->has('foo')) {
    $filesystem->write('foo', 'Some content');
}

echo $filesystem->read('foo');
```

This does not appear to be writing an image file.

I also found [Gaufrette upload image and store in AmazonS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591076/gaufrette-upload-image-and-store-in-amazons3)

but the answer appears to be leaning towards using Gaufrette bundle for Symfony.

I am not using Symfony, so I am hoping for a good example I can use to upload images to S3 via Gaufrette.

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of 'Some content' you can put the variable that represents your image.
How do you get the image?
If it was uploaded by a user you could find it in $_FILES and with the provided temporary filename you could use file_get_contents to read it into a PHP variable.

Comment: sorry about this. i actually moved away from using gaufrette in the end. I assumed your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example writes the text "Some content".
Instead of that you could put your image content.

```
$imageData = file_get_contents('/tmpupload/picture.jpeg');
$filesystem->write('foo', $imageData);
```

You should also write the images mime type to amazon/gaufrette.
If i am not mistaken, this should work:

```
$filesystem->write('foo', $imageData, ['content-type' => 'image/jpeg']);
```

Comment: For 0.2.x, you should call `$filesystem->getAdapter()->setMetadata($filename, array('ContentType' => $mimetype));` to set the mime type. This has to be done before the write.